Quiver and relations for the 0-Hecke algebra
Let $A_n=H_n(0)$ denote the 0-Hecke algebra, see for example König - $0$-Hecke algebras of the symmetric groups.
All simple $A_n$ modules are 1-dimensional and thus $A_n$ is isomorphic to an algebra given by quiver and relations.

Question: Are quiver and admissible relations known for $A_n$ at least for small $n$?

According to the previous thesis, $A_n$ is the direct product $K \times K \times B_n$ for a connected quiver algebra $B_n$ (thus $A_n$ has 3 blocks, where 2 are trivial).
For $n=3$ my calulcations show that $A_n$ is isomorphic to $K \times K \times B$, where $B$ is the preprojective algebra of Dynkin type $A_2$.
What is the result for $n=4$?

You can find the quiver and a basis for all the radical layers in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3455.  I don't remember if they have the relations or if they are known.
